# GTD application for both Mac and Windows

Tags: windows, mac, gtd

I am familiar with GTD applications for Mac OS X, such as Things, the Hit List, etc.
However, I'm trying to find a GTD application that I can use across different OS.

**One main feature I would like to have is real-time synchronization.**
If I update on my macbook, I want to see it updated for the app on Windows. 
Is there a such application?

So far, I was able to find ones that don't have this real-time synchronization across different operating systems.

Comment: Interested in GTD? Join [Personal Productivity and Organization](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296/personal-productivity-and-organization-gtd-covey-etc), we are looking for users & experts... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a web app. [Remember the milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/) does everything you want *and has offline syncing*.

Answer (score 2):

A tool which I use regurlarly is [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com). It has a web interface, and a cross platform client for Windows and MacOSX.

It has a free version as well as a more comprehensive paid for subscription. Not entirely GTD but meets the requirements regarding synchronization and being cross platform, and can be easily adapted for the needs.

Answer (score 1):

Web apps are the best way to get cross-platform sync. (It isn't really sync, you just access the same db from different OS).

I use [Toodledo](http://www.toodledo.com), which has iphone app(s) and also lets you add sidebars and gadgets to your gmail, google calendar and igoogle pages. The iphone app even works when you have no internet access.

If you don't like the idea of a web application, I would suggest you take a look at [chandler](http://chandlerproject.org) which has cross platform clients that can sync over the internet, or some of the tiddlywiki based GTD-mods like [GTDTiddlyWiki plus](http://www.checkettsweb.com/tw/gtd_tiddlywiki.htm).

Tiddlywiki is basically an application written in html and javascript, so it consists of a single html file that you carry with you, all you need to use it is a modern browser.

Answer (score 0):

[Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com/) is cross platform, and the free version provides a very complete feature set.